# How is mousemove handled in IE8 and previous?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, internet-explorer-8, event-handling

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mousemove.html has mousemove events handled on IE8 for document but not window, but I presently have:

```
    try
        {
        document.onmousemove = drag.on_mouse_move;
        }
    catch(error)
        {
        if (typeof document.attachEvent !== undefined)
            {
            document.attachEvent("onmousemove", drag.on_mouse_move);
            }
        }
```

The first real statement throws an error in IE8, as does the last statement. The latter error claims a type mismatch; the former error throws "Not implemented."

How can/should I register a mousemove event listener in IE8(/7/6)?

Comment: Maybe you can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Why deal with that when jQuery handles cross-browser issues for you, ESPECIALLY if you're dealing with older browsers!!

Comment: Its sad how pure JS gets lost in favor of "just use jQuery"...

Comment: @frenchie: that's beginning to change, I've noticed the first questions of X or Y doesn't work in IE<9, dealing with jQuery... besides: some of us just like JS, and don't want to use jQuery _all_ the time, it's good to understand what is really going on behind the scenes in jQuery

Comment: @MalSu: Well I remember developing for IE5 and Netscape 4, before jQuery; it wasn't happiness. For DOM manipulation, pure JS is not better than jQuery but jQuery IS better than pure JS. Just look at this question and tell me why people still try to recreate what jQuery already does?? Here for instance we're recreating $.mousemove(); why?? What benefit?????

Comment: @frenchie You won't always have jQuery available. You could be using any other library. Your environment could restrict the use of external plugins. There are MANY reasons to know what you're doing instead of taking the "why reinvent the wheel" approach, especially when it comes to Web. And no one's "recreating" anything, jQuery didn't invent "onmousemove".

Comment: I cut my teeth as a programmer writing a roguelike in 60,000 lines of C at http://JonathansCorner.com/download/; my father, who is a computer science professor, raised the question about whether I would write in C or C++, and I decided it would be better to do it with the more restricted set of options since, if I could do it with fewer options, then I would be in a position to use more.

Comment: In retrospect, I regard C++ as a language for programmers who have great faith in their own mental powers (<http://lbrandy.com/blog/2010/03/never-trust-a-programmer-who-says-he-knows-c/>) (or are doing what their programmer specifically requests), but on the information I had then, I believe I made the wrong choice. "C is a language that combines the power of assembler with the ease of using assembler;" shooting yourself in the foot in C is for "programmers who prefer to load their own rounds before shooting themselves in the foot." I use Python when I'm not doing front end work.

Comment: But there is merit in "for front end programmers who prefer to load their own rounds before shooting themselves in the foot" bare JavaScript.

Comment: P.S. I've seen people write, "Ajax is the gateway drug to JavaScript." I haven't yet seen someone write that Ajax is the gateway drug to any library or framework.

Comment: @JonathanHayward: libs/toolkits/frameworks like jQuery are gateway drugs to bare JS. Once users find out what JS is _really_ all about, and tinker with node.js or something, they're hooked :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't support IE6, even MS gave up on that browser, thank god. I've just tried the following code in IE8:

```
if (document.attachEvent)
{
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove',function(e)
    {
        e = e || window.event;
        alert(e.type);
    });
}
```

And it worked like a charm. Just a tip: the *normal* try-catch sequence would be:

```
try
{//FF, webkit, opera, IE>8
    document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){},false);
}
catch (e)
{//IE >6 (7?)
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove',function(){});
}
finally
{//browsers that must die
    try
    {
        document.onmousemove = function(){};
    }
    catch(die)
    {
        alert('Use a decent browser.');
        location.href = 'http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/';
    }
}
```

attachEvent is used for delegation, which is to be preferred over direct binding in most cases.